# Grub rescue with no linux partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning, system-installation, grubrescue

I was loading ubuntu off a usb alongside Windows 10, after restarting I am getting the grub rescue menu with "no such partition". I can see my different partitions with ls but all of them return "filesystem is unkown"

Comment: Could you clarify "I was loading ubuntu off a usb alongside Windows 10"? Did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: I have not yet installed ubuntu

Comment: If you didn't install Ubuntu, GRUB shouldn't be in the boot. Did you have a previous linux install?